# Join elements with list with some same attributes

Tags: haskell

I have a list with the type `[(Int, Char, Int)]'. E.g:

```
[(1, 'x', 1), (1, 'y', 2), (2, 'x', 1)]
```

The first `Int` is the number of times the `Char` appears and the second `Int` is to differentiate the same char from each other. For example, there could be x1 and x2.

I want to join elements of that list that have the same 2nd and 3rd element. In the case of the list above, it would become `[(3, 'x', 1), (1, 'y', 2)]` (the first and third tuples from the initial list were added together).

I've looked into `zipWith` and list comprehensions, but none of them seem to work. Is there any other way that I'm not thinking about that might work here?

Answer (score 2):

The two functions you want to use are `Data.List.sortBy` and `Data.List.groupBy`.

If we sort by comparing the second and third elements of each tuple, we get the entries in the list sorted by variable and exponent. This is accomplished by passing a lambda which uses pattern macthing to extract and compare just those elements.

```
import Data.List

lst = [(1, 'x', 1), (1, 'y', 2), (2, 'x', 1)]
lst' = sortBy (\(_, a, b) (_, a', b') -> (a,b) `compare` (a',b')) lst
-- [(1,'x',1), (2,'x',1), (1,'y',2)]
```

Now we need to group based on the second and third values. `groupBy` will not work the way you need on an unsorted list, so don't skip that step.

The lambda being passed to `groupBy` here should look very familiar from the previous example.

```
lst'' = groupBy (\(_, a, b) (_, a', b') -> a == a' && b == b') lst'
-- [[(1,'x',1), (2,'x',1)], [(1,'y',2)]]
```

Now summing the first elements of the tuples and incorporating the other information is trivial with list comprehensions.

We get the variable and exponent info from the first element in the list and bind those to `x` and `y` respectively, then sum up the first coefficients and build a new tuple.

```
[let (_,x,y) = lst!!0 in (sum [c | (c,_,_) <- lst], x, y) | lst <- lst'', not (null lst)]
-- [(3,'x',1), (1,'y',2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest working with more meaningful domain types. A 3-tuple of built-in types could mean a lot of different things. By defining a new type and naming the components, you make everything clearer and prevent mistakes like getting the two `Int`s mixed up:

```
type Power = Int
type Coefficient = Int
data Exp var = Exp var Power deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Term var = Term Coefficient (Exp var) deriving Show
```

What you're doing looks a lot to me like combining terms in polynomials, so I've defined types that make sense in that context. You may prefer different names, or a different structure, if you're actually doing something else.

Now you're looking for a function of type `[Term Char] -> [Term Char]`, which groups together like `Exp`s. Generally `Data.Map.fromListWith` is a great tool for grouping list items together by a key:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

combine :: Ord a => [Term a] -> M.Map (Exp a) Coefficient
combine = M.fromListWith (+) . map toTuple
  where toTuple (Term coef exp) = (exp, coef)
```

Then all that's left is to re-inflate the Map we've extracted to a list again:

```
simplify :: Ord a => [Term a] -> [Term a]
simplify = map fromTuple . M.assocs . combine
  where fromTuple (exp, coef) = Term coef exp
```

And indeed, we get the grouping you hoped for:

```
*Main> simplify [Term 1 (Exp 'x' 1), Term 1 (Exp 'y' 2), Term 2 (Exp 'x' 1)]
[Term 3 (Exp 'x' 1),Term 1 (Exp 'y' 2)]
```

Comment: I am indeed combining terms in polynomials, but I am pretty new to Haskell so I understood basically nothing of what you wrote. I've researched a bit about fromListWith as you mentioned, and I think I understood what it does. I'm now having a hard time changing it from a ```fromList [... , ... , ...]``` to a normal list. Is there any "simple" way to explain that? Because I really don't understand what you did... I'm sorry